# Accessing and storing elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a modified version of `quicksort` in my program that is instructed to sort `pairs` of numbers by the sum of their squares ( for example: `-4,1 > 2,2`). My program works fine with `positive integers`, but when I use too many `negative integers` the program crashes (any more than one or two negative numbers will cause a crash). I think I'm trying to `access` or `sort` undefined parts of the `array` that is storing the `integers`. What is it about `array` storage that I am forgetting? Or is the problem elsewhere?

```
void swap(int *a,int *b);
int square(int num);
int abs_value(int num);
void quicksort(int arr[],int first,int last);

int main()
{
   int num_of_pts;
   int num1;
   int num2;
   printf("Enter number of points: ");//points are coordinates on the xy axis
   scanf("%d", &num_of_pts);          //that's why there is double
   int unsorted_pts_arr[2*num_of_pts];//the amount of storage in the array
   for(int i=0; i<num_of_pts; i++){
      printf("Enter Point: ");
      scanf(" %d",&num1);
      scanf(" %d",&num2);
      unsorted_pts_arr[2*i]=num1;
      unsorted_pts_arr[2*i+1]=num2;
   }
   quicksort(unsorted_pts_arr,0,num_of_pts);
   printf("Sorted Points:");
   for(int j=0; j<num_of_pts; j++)
      printf(" (%d,%d)",unsorted_pts_arr[2*j],unsorted_pts_arr[2*j+1]);
   return 0;
}

void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
   int temp;
   temp = *b;
   *b = *a;
   *a = temp;
}

int square(int num)
{
   num=abs_value(num);
   num*=num;
   return num;
}

int abs_value(int num)
{
   if(num<0) return -num;
   else return num;
}

void quicksort(int arr[],int first,int last)
{
   int pivot,j,i;

   if(first<last){
      pivot=first;
      i=first;
      j=last;

      while(i<j){
         while((square(arr[2*i])+square(arr[2*i+1]))<=
               (square(arr[pivot])+square(arr[pivot+1]))
               &&i<last)
            i++;
         while((square(arr[2*j])+square(arr[2*j+1]))>
               (square(arr[pivot])+square(arr[pivot+1])))
            j--;
         if(i<j){
            swap(&arr[2*i],&arr[2*j]);
            swap(&arr[2*i+1],&arr[2*j+1]);
         }
      }
      swap(&arr[pivot],&arr[2*j]);
      swap(&arr[pivot+1],&arr[2*j+1]);
      quicksort(arr,first,2*j-1);
      quicksort(arr,2*j+1,last);
   }
}
```

Comment: based on what I'm seeing I feel the need to tell you that you can declare and initialize a variable in one statment.  `int temp = *b;` works, and it's better to *not* have uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Main problem**

You are most likely accessing the array out of bounds by using `2*j-1` and `2*j+1` as the array indices in the recursive calls.

```
  quicksort(arr,first,2*j-1);
  quicksort(arr,2*j+1,last);
```

When you call `quicksort` from `main`, `last` is equal to `num_of_pts`. It makes sense that in the recursive calls, you should use `j` and `j+1`.

```
  quicksort(arr,first,j);
  quicksort(arr,j+1,last);
```

**Suggestion for minor improvement**

Implementation of `square` can be simpler.

```
int square(int num)
{
   return num*num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `last` index is `num_of_pts-1`, so

   ```
       quicksort(unsorted_pts_arr,0,num_of_pts);
   ```

   must rather be

   ```
       quicksort(unsorted_pts_arr, 0, num_of_pts-1);
   ```
2. `pivot` is used like `i` and `j` to index a pair of numbers in `arr`, so it must be doubled as well:

   ```
                  (square(arr[pivot])+square(arr[pivot+1]))
   ```

   (both occurences) must be

   ```
                  square(arr[2*pivot])+square(arr[2*pivot+1])
   ```
3. `quicksort` is passed indexes to pairs of numbers (as in `main`), so the arguments of the recursive call also must not be doubled:

   ```
         quicksort(arr,first,2*j-1);
         quicksort(arr,2*j+1,last);
   ```

   must be

   ```
         quicksort(arr, first, j-1);
         quicksort(arr, j+1, last);
   ```